# How i Can Read XML Element and Attribute Values from Below Example

Tags: c#, xml

Below Example How can Get "Airtel" and "145" Values, because my Client Has given this type XML Response
So How Can I Get both Values

```html
<item item="Campaign name" type="string">Airtel</item>
<item item="Daily Limit" type="number">145</item>
```

Comment: We need to see more of the xml file to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, we would need to see the full XML to give you a more complete answer. But you have 3 real options :

- XMLReader. Probably not what you want as it's forward only and involves a lot of manual parsing.
- XMLDocument. Not a bad option if you only want limited amount of notes and want their values and don't want to deserialize the entire XML doc.
- XMLSerializer. Good if you want to deserialize the entire object straight from XML to class without you having to do a heck of a lot.

If you edit your question to include the full XML doc, then I can give you a more complete answer or you can read about your options for parsing XML here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/04/23/how-to-parse-xml-in-net-core/